# Equivalent of dried (ground) pepper when the recipe calls for crushed

Tags: substitutions, ratio

This question is in relation to my earlier question [Recipe calls for Aleppo Peppers, I need the right substitution amounts for cayenne and paprika](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57149/recipe-calls-for-aleppo-peppers-i-need-the-right-substitution-amounts-for-cayen) that I got an answer to. My recipe calls for crushed Aleppo peppers, and I have the proper substitution ratios using paprika and cayenne peppers. Now my question is that I'm actually using ground (dried?) paprika and ground cayenne pepper for the recipe.

The original recipe calls for "2 tablespoons and 3/4 teaspoon crushed paprika and cayenne pepper mix", so my question is how much ground paprika and cayenne pepper mix do I use?

Thanks for the help. :)
Patrick.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've been able to find (looking at crushed red pepper flake substitutions):

[This site](http://www.freshpoint.com/produce/subguide_herbs/herbs_spices_r/red_pepper_flakes.html) says to 2/3s as much ground as crushed:

> Substitute 1⁄2 tsp (2 mL) ground cayenne pepper with:
>
> • 3⁄4 tsp (4 mL) crushed red pepper flakes

I'm not sure why the mL are doubled but the tsp are 2/3s

[This site](http://www.gourmetsleuth.com/ingredients/detail/red-pepper-flakes) says 2/3s as well:

> 1/2 tsp Cayenne powder per 3/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes

So, in your example from your [other question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57149/recipe-calls-for-aleppo-peppers-i-need-the-right-substitution-amounts-for-cayen), you would use 4-1/2 tsp of the chili **powder** mixture (6.75 tsp x .666).

Answer (score -1):

The difference is in the size,  powder=fine, crushed or coarse ground=medium, whole=large, period, the rest can be dictated by taste and personal preference. Unless you're baking recipes are less formula and more subjective. A fine power will be denser (you can pack more small particles into a space than med or lg) and the flavor generally more intense. The general rule is 1/3 more for the larger size e.g., fine powder pepper vs coarse ground pepper.